# Selenium ChromeDriver stop execution after navigating to a different url

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome

So with my selenium app , I'm reading an email , from that email i search for an  tag , get the href off of that (which is always a website link), and do

```cs
driver.Navigate(GoToUrl(url));
```

after that i want to fill some text fields , but this is so inconsistent.
Sometimes it fills all the fields sometimes none. It never partially fills in the fields. I put this line before and after the url change

```cs
Console.WriteLine("testing if selenium hangs")
```

the line before the url change **ALWAYS** executes, but the line after the url change is as inconsistent as the field filling. Sometimes it prints the message to Console sometimes it doesn't , but the program never crashes or reports an exception without and try catches surrounding the code.

```
var activation_link = wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.CssSelector( "#tm-body > main > div.container > div > div.col-sm-12.col-md-12.col-lg-12.col-xl-8 > div.tm-content > div > div.inboxWarpMain > div > div.inbox-data-content > div.inbox-data-content-intro > p:nth-child(2) > a"))); 
var url = activation_link.GetAttribute("href"); 
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url); 
wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.Id("firstName"))).SendKeys_("Gournaks");
```

Comment: Can you please post all the code?

Comment: @osfresia thanks for the edit i had a difficult time figuring how to format my code for Stackoverflow

Comment: Have you tried to pass the url that you captured to `Selenium` alone? Instead of capturing, open as the first url or add a new tab to that webdriver with the desired url.

Comment: Open the url as the starting website works, and selenium doesn't hang . So the problem occurs right after the site presumably loads.

Comment: Please share more your code.

Comment: For some reason , creating new tabs works. Thank you very much.